# Message: Undefined index: secret linkedin login codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, authentication, linkedin-api

I want to integrate LinkedIn login using CodeIgniter. I have successfully created `API key and secret key on LinkedIn` and put into the config folder

```
config/linkedIn.php
```

I have also put libraries files of Linkedin i.e.

```
libraries/linkedin.php
libraries/oAuth/OAuth.php
```

Now, when I put `$this->load->library('Linkedin')` in my default controller then it showing `Message:  Undefined index: access and Message:  Undefined index: secret`. I don't know why?

```
<?php
    require_once("oAuth/OAuth.php");
    class Linkedin {

        public $base_url = "http://api.linkedin.com";
        public $secure_base_url = "https://api.linkedin.com";
        public $oauth_callback = "oob";
        public $consumer;
        public $request_token;
        public $access_token;
        public $oauth_verifier;
        public $signature_method;
        public $request_token_path;
        public $access_token_path;
        public $authorize_path;
        public $debug = false;

        function __construct($options) {

            $consumer_key = $options['access'];
            $consumer_secret = $options['secret'];
            $oauth_callback = isset($options['callback']) ? $options['callback'] : NULL;

            if ($oauth_callback) {
                $this->oauth_callback = $oauth_callback;
            }

            $this->consumer = new OAuthConsumer($consumer_key, $consumer_secret, $this->oauth_callback);
            $this->signature_method = new OAuthSignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1();
            $this->request_token_path = $this->secure_base_url . "/uas/oauth/requestToken?scope=r_fullprofile r_emailaddress r_contactinfo r_network";
            $this->access_token_path = $this->secure_base_url . "/uas/oauth/accessToken";
            $this->authorize_path = $this->secure_base_url . "/uas/oauth/authorize";
        }
        ..............More Code...............
    }
?>
```

So, How can I solve this issue? Please help me.

Thank You

Comment: Do you have a value called secret in the $options parameter?

Comment: where is `$options` coming from? I see you try to use it, but I can't seem to find if your library has it available or not